# Converting dryer to 4 prong

Tags: dryer

I have been looking online on how to do this, but everything I see talks about an existing white cord for the ground. Here's where I'm at. [image]

The wires in front is the new cord, and in the back is how the dryer (Ariston 30616) was set up with the 3 prong cord. Any help?

-edit-

Here's how I set it up:

[image]

And here's the diagram on the dryer:

[image]

Can anyone verify that this is correct?

Comment: Since this is the dryer side of the connection, typically the manual has directions on how to attach both 3 and 4 wire cables to the dryer. Make sure to follow those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks correct. You connected Red and black to L1 and L2, white to Neutral, and green to Ground. Also, you removed the jumper between N and G.

Comment: It's strange. I cut the power, plugged it in, and threw the power back on... Nothing happened. I did remove the ring terminals from the wires, as the one cord used open wires, but they're all securely fastened. Anything else that I might've done incorrectly?

Comment: No idea what might be wrong. If you own an ohm/continuity meter, you could check for connection between the plug terminals (unplugged, of course) and the terminals at the top of the strip.

Comment: Good news, it was the outlet that was disconnected.